# C# Apply action based on user input with adjustment to the input

Tags: c#

Fairly new to C# here, working on a pretty simple code. I have the user to input any number between 1 and 10 and then I want to output a new question with numbers from 1 to (max the users input). Say if the user inputs 7, I want to perform the output with numbers 1 through 7, in order. And when it reaches 7 it stops, based on 7 being the users input.

So, what I don't understand is how to extract/read the variable for which house is in the question and put it in order, and how to stop the loop when it reaches the limit number of the user input. Sorry, feels like a complicated explanation to the question. Hope someone gets it and can provide any help.

Thanks!

Maybe a clear example would be:

```
Console.WriteLine("How many houses did you see? (1-10)");
numhouses = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Great, you saw " + numhouses);

//Gets the numhouses value and starts from 1
//Console.WriteLine("How many windows were on house " + HOUSE 1);

windows1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

//Console.WriteLine("How many windows was on house " + HOUSE 2);

windows2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

//And so on, until it gets to the numhouses value and stops when reached
```

Comment: I suggest you research *collections* (e.g. lists and arrays) and *for loops*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've all been beginners at some point. I'm not going to answer the question for you, as you'll benefit more from working it out, but some pointers to get you going:

1. You've got the number of houses being input by the user, and that works, right? So, you know some of it is correct.
2. Instead of using individual variables for the inputs (`windows1`, `windows2` etc), have a look at a `List<int>` - because you can iterate through a list (loop/repeat). Think of a list as being like a single variable which has `n` slots available for saving different values. Look for how to create a list, and how to add data to it.
3. Look up how to use a `for` loop. This will let you repeat the input question (How many windows) and add the answers to your list.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @chris-k , this helped me move forward!

Answer (score 0):

```
int windows = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("House " + house + " has " + windows + " windows.");
```

Write this logic in the for loop and iterate the loop `numhouses` count u will get the answer. just do [some basic research about for loop](https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_for_loop.php)